# Linux Routing Question, more specific route still using default route

Tags: linux, route

Trying to route NNN.130.0.0 via NNN.NNN.206.254 however it appears to still be using the default gateway.  What am I missing here?

```
root@xxxxxx ~ # route add -net NNN.130.0.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 gw NNN.NNN.206.254 eth0
root@xxxxxx ~ # route -n
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway           Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
NNN.130.0.0     NNN.NNN.206.254   255.255.255.0   UG    0      0        0 eth0
NNN.NNN.240.0   NNN.NNN.192.1     255.255.254.0   UG    0      0        0 eth0
NNN.NNN.248.0   NNN.NNN.193.1     255.255.254.0   UG    0      0        0 eth0
172.21.124.0    NNN.NNN.193.1     255.255.252.0   UG    0      0        0 eth0
172.20.124.0    NNN.NNN.192.1     255.255.252.0   UG    0      0        0 eth0
NNN.NNN.64.0    NNN.NNN.193.1     255.255.248.0   UG    0      0        0 eth0
NNN.NNN.128.0   NNN.NNN.192.1     255.255.248.0   UG    0      0        0 eth0
NNN.NNN.0.0     NNN.NNN.192.1     255.255.248.0   UG    0      0        0 eth0
NNN.NNN.160.0   NNN.NNN.193.1     255.255.248.0   UG    0      0        0 eth0
NNN.NNN.192.0   0.0.0.0           255.255.240.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
NNN.9.0.0       0.0.0.0           255.255.240.0   U     0      0        0 eth1
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0           255.255.0.0     U     1002   0        0 eth0
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0           255.255.0.0     U     1003   0        0 eth1
0.0.0.0         NNN.NNN.192.1     0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0

root@xxxxxx ~ # ip route get NNN.130.20.35
NNN.130.20.35 via NNN.NNN.192.1 dev eth0  src NNN.NNN.192.62
```

Comment: Are all those `NNN` exactly the same? If not, please go back and add a set of self-consistent values. So `N` might be `192` everywhere, and `M` might be `172` everywhere, and so on, but each letter will never represent anything other than one value.

Comment: All values are the same. You can replace with 222. so 222.222.206.254 would be valid for NNN.NNN.206.254.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no explicit route for the address `NNN.130.20.35` so it takes the default.

I wonder if you're muddling `NNN.130.20.35` with the unrelated subnet `NNN.130.0.0/24`.